# Make Toolbar transparent as in Newsstand App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am trying to make my toolbar transparent as in the image below. I am trying to achieve this programmatically.

[image]

What is the difference between translucent and transparent toolbar in android?

Please refer to the code below and image below that, to understand what i am upto till now. Please point me in the right direction.

```
public void hideToolbar() {
    // toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
}

public void showToolbar() {
    // toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(255);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
        attrs.flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        attrs.flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(
                Color.parseColor(Const.Colors.COLOR_STATUS_BLUE));
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

I want both toolbar and status bar to be transparent. Let me know if you need any of my xmls or other code.

Comment: have you tried `toolbar.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);`.

Answer (score 0):

I can make clear your understanding about the difference between Transparent and Translucent.

- Transparent means you can completely see-through an object. We can
  take glass for the example.
- Translucent means the state between opaque and transparent, you can
  also call it semi-transparent. From translucent object, you can't
  see-through a image behind it clearly, BUT some amount of light can
  pass through that object. We can take paper as example of translucent
  object. As we put paper above the light source(for example torch),
  you can see the light, but not the torch.

I am not a pro in android coding, but I gave you how much I know about.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the colors of the content behind the toolbar can collide with the color of the toolbar elements/text (up/back arrow for example) a lot of implementations of the toolbar are actually not transparent but translucent with a gradient.

You can obtain this with the next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent" />
```

background_toolbar_translucent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_40"/>
</shape>
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>
```

You can play with different values on the gradient, what I've found is that for white elements, the black 40% works fine.